# Nodejs blocks and can't process next requests during ZIP file streaming

Tags: node.js, express, stream

I'm trying to create a simple app which will create ZIP on the fly containg a few files and stream them to the client. Almost works. The problem what I encountered is that the nodejs blocks when streaming is in progress. All pendig requests will be processed after finishing current streaming. But what is interesting, **these pending requests will be processed concurrently!** So it can do this! I don't understand, why nodejs (expressjs?) can't start processing next request during streaming one file and what I did wrong... :|

I'm using node-archiver as a stream source.

Here's my part of code:

```
var express = require('express');
var archiver = require('archiver');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/job/:id', function(req, res) {
    var job = req.jobs[req.params.id];

    var archive = archiver('zip');
    archive.pipe(res);

    for (var n in job.files) {
        var f = job.files[n];
        archive.file(job.path + f, {name: f});
    }

    res.setHeader("content-type", "application/zip");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="reports.zip"')
    archive.finalize();
});

module.exports = router;
```

Any advices? Thanks!

EDIT: I've noticed another problem, completely not related with archiver. I have following basic app:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var stream = fs.createReadStream('file.blob');
    stream.pipe(res);
});
server.listen(31922);
```

Tell me, why it get stuck in this case? Result is absolutely the same as using archiver. OS what I use is SmartOS (based on Open Solaris), it's Unix. Maybe this is a problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Try `archive.append(fs.createReadStream(job.path + f), { name: f })` and see what happens.

Comment: @Kekas, I'm afraid this get stuck on different part of code. I tried to stream a simple file by `var file = fs.createReadStream('file.blob'); file.pipe(res);` and the result is exactly the same! :| So this is not a problem with archiver. I will let you know when I find something interesing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all those of you struggling with similar problem. I'm being dumb perhaps. The solution is simple. Basically testing method was wrong. My browser (and other tested have similar behaviour) blocks processing next request from the same host name when previous one is not finished. And in this case this is not finished request as downloading is still in progress. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Archiver` depends on synchronous code, there is recent issue open on github  addressing this:

https://github.com/ctalkington/node-archiver/issues/85

Given that it is synchronous, that's probably where your block is comming from.

Quote:

> This module depends on file-utils which in the README says: "this is a
>   set of synchronous utility. As so, it should never be used on a
>   Node.js server. This is meant for users/command line utilities."